# Java FX not working because can't detect Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to run Java FX on eclipse and it gives me an error saying it can't run because Eclipse isn't starting off with Java 8. I have however done the `java -version` command which tells me I am using Java 8 and I've gone ahead and checked on Eclipse and I am indeed linking Eclipse to Java 8 as is shown in the picture below. Has anyone encountered this problem and knows how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: By "Run JavaFX" you mean you are trying to execute a JavaFX Application, or build one? When are you getting this error?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the -vm option for your Eclipse installation. Set this in your eclipse.ini file which should be located in the same folder as your eclipse executable.

For more info : https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: When I change that I get an error now saying `1.7 jvm or greater required` and eclipse doesn't open

Comment: You need to change the location to your jdk 18 location